# return column name of the maximum value in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

My table looks like this (Totally different names)

```
ID   Column1--Column2---Column3--------------Column30 
X       0       2          6       0101          31
```

I want to find the **second maximum** value of Column1 to Column30 and Put the column_Name in a seperate column.

First row would look like :

```
ID   Column1--Column2---Column3--------------Column30------SecondMax
X       0       2          6       0101          31         Column3
```

Query :

```
      Update Table
      Set SecondMax= (select Column_Name from table  where ...)
```

Comment: Does this table have only one record?

Comment: @BenisonSam No Dear, It has 500K records

Comment: And what do you do with ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with unpvt as (
    select id, c, m
    from T
    unpivot (c for m in (c1, c2, c3, ..., c30)) as u /* <-- your list of columns */
)
update T
set SecondMax = (
    select top 1 m
    from unpvt as u1 
    where
        u1.id = T.id
        and u1.c < (
            select max(c) from unpvt as u2 where u2.id = u1.id
        )                    
    order by c desc, m
)
```

I really don't like relying on top but this isn't a standard sql question anyway. And it doesn't do anything about ties other than returning the first column name by order of alphabetical sort.

You could use a modification via the condition below to get the "third maximum". (Obviously the constant 2 comes from 3 - 1.) Your version of SQL Server lets you use a variable there as well. I think SQL 2012 also supports the `limit` syntax if that's preferable to `top`. And since it should work for top 0 and top 1 as well, you might just be able to run this query in a loop to populate all of your "maximums" from first to thirty.

Once you start having ties you'll eventually get a "thirtieth maximum" that's null. Make sure you cover those cases though.

```
        and u1.c < all (
            select top 2 distinct c from unpvt as u2 where u2.id = u1.id
        )
```

And after I think about it. If you're going to rank and update so many columns it would probably make even more sense to use a proper ranking function and do the update all at once. You'll also handle the ties a lot better even if the alphabetic sorting is still arbitrary.

```
with unpvt as (
    select id, c, m, row_number() over (partition by id order by c desc, m) as nthmax
    from T
    unpivot (c for m in (c1, c2, c3, ..., c30)) as u /* <-- your list of columns */
)
update T set
    FirstMax = (select c from unpvt as u where u.id = T.id and nth_max = 1),
    SecondMax = (select c from unpvt as u where u.id = T.id and nth_max = 2),
    ...
    NthMax = (select c from unpvt as u where u.id = T.id and nth_max = N)
```

Comment: Names of columns produced by the unpivot operation. Try running the unpvt query by itself to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, I did. Although I will bite my tongue and not ask why you want this.

Comment: :D it's a completely different problem. Column names are cities and their values are number of being visited by each customer. I have already found favorite city of each customer. now, i wanted to find the second favorite.

Comment: I hope it works for you. But you might find yourself doing a lot of unpivots and then asking yourself why you didn't just store the data that way in the first place.

Comment: Are ties not going to be an issue?

Comment: how about the third maximum? :D

Comment: I knew you would ask that.